# Is AWS' certificate authority necessary for me to have if I already have my private certs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

This may be a weird question but I created a Client VPN and in doing so it was necessary for me to create a server certificate and key both of which I imported. The VPN is working fine, but I am now being hit with a $400 pro-rated charge for Amazon's Private Certification Authority service. I don't remember ever using this, I think I might have created one by accident.

Is it safe to delete this? I don't think it should effect my VPN, I created the necessary certificates for that.

Comment: Best get in touch with AWS Support. If you created something by accident they are probably able to help you resolve the issue.

Comment: The problem isn't that I created it by accident. I just want to know if I need that Private CA, I'm a newbie at this so I am pretty sure I created it a month ago thinking I needed it and that it  was free so I left it there. But I've since created a VPN tunnel correctly and it never involved using that Private CA. thanks for your reply

Comment: I’m pretty sure that you don’t need a private CA for a Client VPN connection.

Comment: Yes me too, I just deleted it and the VPN connection is fine. Thank you for the reassurance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need this, and instead can use pre-shared keys. The Amazon PCA allows you to use IKE type keys. It is not necessary. From the client-guide

> To create a Client VPN endpoint, you must provision a server certificate in AWS >Certificate Manager, regardless of the type of authentication you use. For more >information about creating and provisioning a server certificate, see the steps in Mutual authentication.

More information can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/client-authentication.html

Also, from direct work experience - you should contact AWS about that cert - especially if you haven't used it. They can waive it or provide you equal credits on your next bill.

Comment: Yes you're right, that's exactly what I did. It looks like I had it there by accident, I just deleted it. And thank you for the advice I'll contact them. The private CA is pro-rated at $400 a month. Since I just deleted it does that mean I'll only be charged for Jan 1 - 3rd? So like $13

Comment: If you are a private user, running a development/learning workload - let them know that in the email you send to billing. Something akin to: during my experimentation with AWS, I accidentally provisioned this certificate, but deleted it immediately. Can you please make sure the amount for the cert is pro-rated, or can it be waived?

Comment: According to this: https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/pricing/ it is indeed pro-rated. But I'll for sure ask them like you said, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using AWS Private CA, you can import your own certificates to ACM  from your private CA, using tools like easy-rsa.

VPN docs shows a way you can create your CA using easy-rsa: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/mutual.html

After you import the server cert, it will appear as available when configuring your VPN Client Connection. Then you can create client certs to allow them to connect to your VPN.